# What does this filter code means?

Tags: informatica-powercenter

IIF(ASCII(A) >= 48  AND ASCII(A)  <= 57, TRUE, FALSE)

Does anyone have any idea what does ASCII do here and what does the code try to accomplish?
I ran into this filter condition on our informatica and I am not an ETL developer.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This tests whether `A` is a digit character, i.e. is a character between `'0'` and `'9'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it checks if A is in interval between 48 and 57 position in ASCII table.

Looks like it's check for numbers. (it's 0 to 9).

Check this out - [LINK](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The filter will pass the records for which the field A starts with a number.